# What's the line setting vim option at the bottom of a text file called?

Tags: vim

The line looks like this

```
.. vim: set ft=help norl ts=8 tw=78 et :
```

And appears at the bottom of some text files, such as vim documentation.

I just want to know where I can look this topic up in the vim help to read about it.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It is called a modeline.

See `:help modeline` for more information.

Basically, it is a way to tell Vim how to render a text file.

Answer (score 5):

It’s called a modeline. Try:

```
:help modeline
```

Answer (score 4):

That is the modeline.

```
:help modeline
```